# Change the image of the UV/image editor with python for 2.8

Tags: python, scripting, uv-image-editor

i want to change the active image of my uv/editor with codes, i dont know how to do this in 2.8

could someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
        area.spaces.active.image = bpy.data.images['Your_image_name']
```

Deactivate image in Image Editor

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
        area.spaces.active.image = None
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed this to work even if Image Editor is in different window so I used an additional loop for Bleneder windows:

```
import bpy
img = bpy.data.images.load('My Image.png')
for window in bpy.data.window_managers['WinMan'].windows:
    for area in window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
            area.spaces.active.image = img
```